# List of manga chapters animated in Hayate no Gotoku! Cuties

Tags: hayate-no-gotoku

If you have been following the manga, you would notice that *Hayate no Gotoku! - Cuties* (season 4 of the series) has been using material from:

- "Filler" manga chapters (where plot stalls for character development) for most part of the episodes.
- 4-koma style manga from *Colorful Hayate no Gotoku!* **or** from the flaps of the dust-jacket of the tankōbon for the *CM Connecting Theater* (*CM Matagi Gekijou*).

Can anyone provide a list of manga chapters that is animated per episode?

Answer (score 6):

The titles of the chapters are arrange in order of appearance in the anime. The anime also added some original content to create smooth transition between unrelated chapters.

In order not to confuse viewer (?), even though the anime draws material from various arcs in the manga, they are modified (sometimes heavily) to fit the pretext that all characters have known each other, and with all the details involving the plot (from where the chapter comes from) removed.

<sup>*Chapter titles are taken from [Wikipedia - List of Hayate the Combat Butler chapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hayate_the_Combat_Butler_chapters). Title of 4-koma manga are taken from scanslation.*</sup>

**Episode 1**

**Hayate** episode.

- Chapter 303: "An Ordinary Life That KyoAni Wouldn't Turn Into an Anime" (京アニがアニメ化とかしない方の日常?)
- Chapter 352: "Illness begins in the mind. That means you will get sick if you neglect your mind." (病は気から。気を抜くと病気になると言う意味)
- 4-koma ??
- 4-koma Colorful Chapter 24: Hermione and The Secret Clothes
- Chapter 353: "He Caught A Cold Because He is No Longer An Idiot" (バカじゃなくなったからカゼをひく)

**Episode 2**

**Nagi** episode.

- Chapter 197: "If You Feel Like You Have Become a Little Greater When You Wake Up Early in the Morning... Then You Are Imagining Things" (朝早く起きるとちょっと自分がエラくなったような気がする…という気のせい)
- Chapter 174: "Even if the Law Says You Can't, You Still Want to See it" (法律でダメって言われても、観たい気持ちは消えない)
- 4-koma Colorful Chapter 16: Sanzenin Nagi's Less Than Beneficial Information
- 4-koma Colorful Chapter 5: The Wild Kingdom
- Chapter 339: "A Single Yen Can Make One Laugh or Cry" (１円に泣いたり笑ったり)

**Episode 3**

**A-tan** (as Alice) episode.

- Chapter 306: "It's an Option That Comes Default on Little Blonde Girls" (金髪幼女にはデフォルトでついてるオプションです)
- Chapter 316: "Don't Move Another Step" (もうお前一歩も動くな)
- Chapter 317: "If it's Important, Keep it with you" (大事なら持っとけ)
- 4-koma ??
- 4-koma ??
- Chapter 318: "Sign"
- Chapter 346: "And The Butler Made Them" (そして執事はそれを作ったとさ)

**Episode 4**

**Isumi** and **Sakuya** episode.

- Chapter 341: "A Maid Will Not Be Found For Isumu-San Until 23rd Century" (伊澄さんのメイドさんは２３世紀まで見つからない)
- 4-koma Volume 29 (Front): Hi-tech Isumi-san ~Eps. Smartphone~
- 4-koma Volume 29 (Back): Hi-tech Isumi-san ~Eps. App~
- Chapter 175: "You Bump Into Everyone You Need in Life" (人生に必要な人とはだいたい出会うようにできている)
- Chapter 309: "The Honorific "Onee-san" is Filled With Romance" (敬語お姉さんが恋愛で満たされて)

**Episode 5**

**Hinagiku** episode. The anime didn't follow chapter 340 too closely (only around 50% of manga stays the same in the anime), but it makes the story better. For chapter 220 to 223, which occurs during the Golden Week in the manga, all the inheritance related stuffs are excluded in the anime.

- (Up to just before the end of) Chapter 340: "Hinagiku-San's Wish Does Not Seem As If It Will Be Granted Even If She Uses The Holy Grail" (ヒナギクさんの願いは聖杯を使っても叶いそうにない)
- (Start from near the end of) Chapter 220: "The Time to Forget Your Troubles Has Come. The Memory Mechanism Is Still Scientifically Unclear" (トラブルは忘れた頃にやってくる)
- Chapter 221: "Because You Go to the Beach, There's Something You Have to Do" (ビーチに来たからにはやる事がある)
- 4-koma Volumn 12 (Front): Into the Dream, Into the Dream
- 4-koma Volumn 12 (Back): Don't you want to go?
- Chapter 222: "Love Makes People Run in Odd Directions And Then They Want to Die" (恋は人をおかしな方向に走らせる。後で死にたくなる)
- Chapter 223: "Winning And Happiness Are Equal But Not Linked" (勝つことと幸せはイコールで結ばれない)
- (The rest of chapter 340)

**Episode 6**

**Izumi, Miki, Risa** (Idiot Trio) episode.

- Chapter 356: "Even with Three Heads, 'Hmm...I Dunno' is all the Three can Come up with" ( 三人寄ってもう～ん…どうなんやろ…って三人で悩むだけ)
- Chapter 373: Pros Are Amazing In My Field
- 4-koma Volume 28 (Front): If you can't concentrate, you can't do anything.
- 4-koma Volume 28 (Back): With the ability to concentrate, you can do anything.
- Chapter 308: "Carelessness Means Acting Carelessly in Careless Moments" (うっかりは、うっかりしている時にうっかりする)
- (Plus the first page of chapter 309, which is animated after the ED sequence).

**Chapter 6**

**Ruka** episode. There are quite a number of differences between anime and manga in the second part. In the manga, chapter 292 to 299 covers the first meeting between Hayate and Ruka, and the first meeting between Nagi and Ruka. These chapter also involves *Housen Yozora* (法仙 夜空) chasing after Hayate to destroy a fragment of photo that Hayate is holding on to. In the anime, which animates content of chapter 298 and first half of chapter 299, the story has been modified under the pretext that Ruka has known everyone else in the apartment, and *Housen Yozora* is replaced by *Gilbert Kent*.

- Chapter 357: "Cycling Yahoo!" (サイクリング ヤッホー)
- Chapter 358: "To be Blunt, I am an S at the Core. Also, Never do what I do!!" (ぶっちゃけ根はどSなのです。あと絶対マネしちゃダメ！！)
- 4-koma ??
- 4-koma ??
- Chapter 298: "Idol Master" (アイドルマスター?)
- (First half of) Chapter 299: "Don't Stop! Dreamer on the Road!"